# Creating New Calendar Items in Different Subsite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, calendar

I have a leave request calendar setup on our department site that is connected to a SPD 13 customized approval workflow. Originally, I wanted to be able to have it create a calendar item in another calendar in addition, but I soon came to realize that you can't use that action to copy into other sites, even sites within the same site collection.

The request has come up again to make this happen, but I'm not sure what to do. Any help or resources is appreciated.

Comment: Since you are on SharePoint online use MS Flow.  It would be much easier to create item to subsite or even different site collection.

Comment: I thought of that, but Flow won't recognize the list since its a calendar. :-(

Comment: You can use calendar type list!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MS Flow to create calendar item in different site collection.  You will need to enter custom value to get the calendar list:

[Here are the details](http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/10/20/create-calendar-events-in-different-sharepoint-site-using-flow/)

Comment: Can you join this chat group to discuss this?
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67511/ms-flow-creating-calendar-events-in-different-sp-site-collections

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event receiver to monitor the events in the calendar and then create events in another calendar in the another subsite.

For SharePoint online, we can use remote event receiver to handle events.

Demoes about using remote event receiver in SharePoint online:

[Event receivers and list event receivers in the SharePoint add-in model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/event-receiver-and-list-event-receiver-sharepoint-add-in)

[Attaching Remote Event Receivers to Lists in the Host Web](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043978/Remote-Event-Receivers-RER-in-SharePoint-Online)